# K8s - Schedule new pod before the old one is terminated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have read up on the Kubernetes docs but I'm unable to get a clear answer on my question. I'm using the official cluster-autoscaler.

1. I have a deployment that specifies one replica should be running. When a pod is terminated (for example, was running on a node that is getting scaled-down) **is the new pod scheduled before the termination begins or after the termination is done?** The docs say that schedule happens when terminating, but don't mention at which phase.
2. To achieve seamless node scale-down without disruption to any services, I would expect k8 to scale up pods to N+1 replicas (at this point pods are scheduled only to nodes that are not scaling down) and then drain the node. Based on my testing, it first drains, and then schedules any missing pods based on configurations. **Is it possible to configure this behaviour or this is currently not possible to do?**

From what I understand, seamless updates are easy with RollingUpdate strategy. I have not find the same "Rolling" strategy to be possible for scale-down.

**EDIT**

TL;DR I'm looking for HA on a) two+ replica deployment and b) one replica deployment

a) Can be achieved by using PDBs. Checkout Fritz's answer. If you need pods scheduled on different nodes, leverage anti-affinity (Marc's answer)

b) If you're okay with short disruption, PDB is the official way to go. If you need a workaround, my answer can be of inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scale down behavior can be configured with what is called a [Disruption Budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-disruption-budgets-work)

In your Deployment Manifest you can define `maxUnavailable` and `minAvailable` number of Pods during voluntary disruptions like draining nodes.

For how to do it, check out [the K8s Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#protecting-an-application-with-a-poddisruptionbudget).

Comment: Thanks Fritz!
I'm already using PDBs for the autoscaler itself but I skipped the documentation on it.
Interestingly, it says that `The deployment notices that one of the pods is terminating, so it creates a replacement called pod-d` that contradicts the previous notation saying new pod is scheduled *after* the termination.

Anyway, PDBs are helpful but they don't answer the question on how to not waste resources and create HA with only one service replica

Answer (score 2):

Hate to answer my own question, but an easy solution to high-availability service with only one pod (not wasting resources with running one idle replica) is to use `PreStop` hook (to make the action blocking if proper SIGTERM handling is not implemented) together with `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` with enough time for the other service to start.

Contradicting to what has been said here, the scheduling happens when pod is terminating. After quick testing (should have done that together with reading docs) where I created a busybox (sh sleep 3600) deployment with one replica and `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` set to 240 seconds.

By deleting the pod, it will enter the Terminating state and stay in that state for 240 seconds. Immediately after **marking** the pod as Terminating, new pod was scheduled instead of it.
So the previous pod has time to finish whatever it is doing and the other one can *seamlessly* take its place.

I haven't tested how will the networking behave since LB will stop sending new requests, but I assume the downtime will be much lower than without the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` set to a higher amount than the default.

Beware that is not official by any means but serves as a workaround for my use case.

Comment: I don't believe it's non-sense. Both answers are correct. Using anti-affinity and PDB is a good way to achieve HA across zones.
I have updated my question to make it a bit more clear.
And yes, I understand what `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` is for, but there is no other workaround on how to achieve HA on for one replica. I understand that HA and just one pod don't go together, but it's required for my use case. I have updated my answer to make it clear this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some insight, hope this will help :

1. If you use a deployment, then the scheduler checks that you always have the desired number of replicas running. No less, no more. So when you *kill* a node (which have one of your replicas), the new pod will be scheduled **after** the termination of one of your original replicas. It's up to you to anticipate if it's a planified maintenance.
2. If you have lots of nodes (meaning more than one) and want to achieve HA (high availability) for your deployments, then you should have a look at **pod affinity/anti-affinity**. You can find out more [in the official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity)

Comment: Thanks, Marc! Seems like the combination of affinity and anti-affinity will do the trick. I was hopeful that there might be some magic parameter which will do it for me and I won't have to go through the editing of configurations :)

But what about services with only one replica? Based on the answer to 1. question, it's impossible to have HA with only one replica, right?
It would be wasteful to run 2 replicas at all times only to achieve HA.

Comment: That's the first rule of HA : you can't have it with only one replicas (be it on k8s or any other system). So yes, **you'll have to** have at least two replicas. Also, i just found out that in v1.18 [pod topology spread constraint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/) went beta. You can have a look at it if it's simpler or not than pod anti-affinity. Personnally i did not try it out.

Comment: That looks promising! Just gotta wait until AWS EKS updates...
Thanks a lot again for providing this info, I will close it as answered.

Comment: pod affinity/anti-affinity for high availability? first time hearing of it. wrong answer!